# how to export module in father module to child

Tags: angular, import, module, export, lazy-loading

I have HomeModule, inside I have imports SharedModule with angular material and ToolbarModule. My doubt is how can I just import SharedModule in HomeModule and exports to all child modules, because I am import SharedModule for the child modules. Follow the code:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    SharedModule,
    ToolbarModule
  ],
  exports: [
    HomeComponent
  ]
})
export class HomeModule { }

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    SharedModule
  ]
})
export class ToolbarModule { }
```

What is the best practice? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular works that way, you will have to import all modules that you need inside the @NgModule. So you will have to import `SharedModule` as many times as you need it.

So your code is correct!

Comment: Got it! Thanks a lot! One doubt, inside that, will import twice sharedModule? haha